# Crystal Report when Group footer print on page suppress page footer

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

```
page header (letter head header) <br>
group header <br>
detail <br>
group footer  (print grand total and terms and conditions) <br>
page footer A (print note) <br>
page footer B (print subtotal of specific page) <br>
page footer C (show page N of M) <br>
page footer C (letter head footer) <br>
<br>
```

when my **group footer** display or print or pages 
how to suppress **page footer  B**

currently im using this

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 
booleanVar ShowGroupFooter;
booleanVar ShowPageFooter;
if ShowGroupFooter:= yes then
OnLastRecord  or PageNumber = TotalPageCount;
```

Comment: By the way, its not necessary to add <br> to your posts

Comment: im using for next line

Comment: We don't author posts in HTML. That's what the **Enter** key on your keyboard is for